# Missing MEM and CPU usage for pod in the kubernetes-dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I am running k8s 1.15 in azure and based on the guide:

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-and-graph-kubernetes-metrics/

I have started the kubernetes dashboard (`mcr.microsoft.com/oss/kubernetes/kubernetes-dashboard:v1.10.1`) running on localhost. But I don't see the (limited) timeseries of MEM and CPU usage as shown in:

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-and-graph-kubernetes-metrics/

https://imgix.datadoghq.com/img/blog/how-to-collect-and-graph-kubernetes-metrics/kubernetes-dashboard-pod.png?auto=format&fit=max&w=847

When I click a specific pod I just see:

[image]

Where are the MEM and CPU usage graphs?

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to enable necessary permission.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: I was asking @u123 ;)